# SearchView with a suggestion CursorAdapter attached, being extremely slow?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-cursoradapter, searchview

I set up my searchview like follows:

```
searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

searchAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listentry, null, new String[] { "name" }, new int[] { R.id.name_entry }, 0);

searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(searchAdapter);
```

I create the `SimpleCursorAdapter` here and set it as a suggestions adapter to the `SearchView` object. Then, in the `onQueryTextChanged` method I have this:

```
searchAdapter.changeCursor(dbHelper.runAlgorithms(q)); //"q" is the text from searchview
```

Here is what is in my `runAlgorithms` method:

```
q = q.replace("'", "%27");
q = q.replace("%", "\\%");
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, desc, data FROM verbs WHERE name_unaccented LIKE '" + q + "' ESCAPE '\\'", null);
return c;
```

However, every time all this is called (every time I hit a key in the searchview) it skips around 50 to 150 frames every time, which is way too much. What could be the problem/what could be slowing down the suggestions? Is this the right way of doing this? The table being queried has ~7500 rows.

Comment: why not just do this asynchronously? Throw it in an `AsyncTask`, also 50 frames is not much, but is it lagging the key inputs?

Comment: @Matt using the AsyncTask still isnt stopping the lag from the key inputs, do you think there may be another method I'm missing in how to do this searchview and database attaching?

Comment: Well, I think the normal implementation is to use a `ContentProvider`, I am using that in one of my apps and works well and on each key my data is downloaded from the internet and not much lag. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html and a tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Of course a `ContentProvider` is not required for your implementation, and IMO is a lot of work. Using a handler and a runnable would be a little faster than `AsyncTask` but I'm pretty sure your issue is with the database search, however, the search should definitely not be performed on the UI thread; this will alleviate the lag (there should be none). And, just to be clear, by lag I mean "not being able to press another key until `runAlgorithms` returns", not "takes a while for suggestions to appear"